# Spring data reactive Cassandra not creating keyspace on startup - InvalidQueryException: Keyspace 'xxx' does not exist

Tags: spring-data, reactive-programming, reactive, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring data reactive Cassandra. Given below is my configuration class. My expectation is that when the spring boot application loads it has to connect to Cassandra and create the keyspace. But my application is able to connect to Cassandra but it is not creating the keyspace. I am getting the below exception on startup. Please let me know if i am missing something.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.DropKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.KeyspaceOption;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contactpoints}") private String contactPoints;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}") private int port;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}") private String keyspace;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}") private String userName;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}") private String password;
    @Value("${cassandra.basepackages}") private String basePackages;


    @Override protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keyspace;
    }
    @Override protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }
    @Override protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    @Override public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }
    @Override public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[] {
                basePackages
        };
    }

    @Override
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        PlainTextAuthProvider authProvider = new PlainTextAuthProvider(userName, password);

        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster=new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();

        cluster.setJmxReportingEnabled(false);
        cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cluster.setPort(port);
        cluster.setAuthProvider(authProvider);
        cluster.setReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(1000));

        return cluster;
    }



    @Override
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {

        CreateKeyspaceSpecification specification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(keyspace)
                .ifNotExists()
                .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true);

        return Arrays.asList(specification);
    }


    @Override
    protected List<DropKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceDrops() {
        return Arrays.asList(DropKeyspaceSpecification.dropKeyspace(keyspace));
    }

}
```

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 5; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘myRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'reactiveCassandraOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' defined in com.company.domain.CassandraConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.ReactiveCassandraTemplate]: Factory method 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveSessionFactory' defined in com.company.domain.CassandraConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.ReactiveSessionFactory]: Factory method 'reactiveSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveSession' defined in com.company.domain.CassandraConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.ReactiveSession]: Factory method 'reactiveSession' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.company.domain.CassandraConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace ‘mykeyspace’ does not exist**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it fixed by the below code. We need to setKeyspaceCreations on CassandraClusterFactoryBean and also enable @ComponentScan.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.*;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.DropKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.KeyspaceOption;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.domain.data")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration{
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contactpoints}") private String contactPoints;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}") private int port;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}") private String keyspace;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}") private String userName;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}") private String password;
@Value("${cassandra.basepackages}") private String basePackages;


@Override protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keyspace;
}
@Override protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoints;
}
@Override protected int getPort() {
    return port;
}
@Override public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
}
@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[]{"com.company.domain.data"};
}

@Override
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    PlainTextAuthProvider authProvider = new PlainTextAuthProvider(userName, password);

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster=new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();

    cluster.setJmxReportingEnabled(false);
    cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
    cluster.setPort(port);
    cluster.setAuthProvider(authProvider);
    cluster.setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations());
    cluster.setReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(1000));

    return cluster;
}


@Override
protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {

    CreateKeyspaceSpecification specification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(keyspace)
            .ifNotExists()
            .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true);

    return Arrays.asList(specification);
}



@Override
protected List<DropKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceDrops() {
    return Arrays.asList(DropKeyspaceSpecification.dropKeyspace(keyspace));
}



}
```